# How does SWIFT work?

Tags: edi, eai, swift-mt

I would like to understand the way SWIFT messages work. I tried to understand from Google and it says that it uses packet switched network mechanism.

It would be of great favour if somebody can throw light on the following questions

1. Whether SWIFT by itself a communication protocol like AS2
2. For Trade finance system if I use IMEX does using a SWIFT message requires any Adapter kind of components with IMEX
3. Architecture of SWIFT

Comment: Please don't write titles in all-caps.

Answer (score 2):

How SWIFT works is a big subject, but it's basically a proprietary protocol driven by the needs of the SWIFT community.

Since it all started in the early days of computing, the core stuff uses the UNIX philosophy of: write programs to do one thing, do it well, and use text as your inter program communication.

So, to take FIN messaging, SWIFT works using ASCII text files across a secure network.

To be able to send and receive these text files you need to join SWIFT. See http://www.swift.com/ordering/join_swift

The architecture is proprietary, but, once you join SWIFT you can send and receive specifically formatted text files, or, in the "next generation" it's XML but, to me, that is trying to re-invent the UNIX philosophy, which is bound to fail, and be very expensive in the process. But apparently this is what clients wanted...........?

So there you have it...